# Loading a texture2D in a separate class using c# and xna

Tags: c#, xna, texture2d

I have been adding a bunch of textures to my game in xna so i decided to make a separate class to load and draw the textures.

this is what i have so far

```
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamerServices;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media;


namespace Trolls_and_Towers
{

class Textures
{
    //Texture loading

        //Buttons
    public static Texture2D button;


    public static void Load()
    {
        Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game game = new Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game();
        button = game.Content.Load<Texture2D>("button");
    }

    public static void Draw()
    {
        Game1.spriteBatch.Draw(button, new Rectangle(20, Game1.screenHeight - 70, 100, 50), Color.White);
    }
}
}
```

the problem is that it can't find the button texture and i know it isn't spelt wrong as when i load it in the Load method of my game it works

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you create a new XNA project there is this inside the constructor :

```
    public Game1()
    {
        _graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
        Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
    }
```

Alternatively you could do the following :

```
    class Game
    {

    }

    class TextureManager
    {
        public TextureManager(Game game)
        {

        } 
    }
```

Note, https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/ will be a better place for you to ask game-dev related questions.

Answer (score -1):

You can also call your load-method from The game1-loadcontent-void ans gibe content-Manager as a parameter. Then you can call Content.Loaf in The other class as well.